# plot histogram after averaging images

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library, histogram

I have the following code to average a set of images (say 100 images) and to plot the histogram of the averaged image (one image). I am not getting the histogram with this code. Could you please help me in this code.

---

```
# reading multiple images
 S01=[i for i in glob.glob("C:/Users/experiment 1/S01/*.tif")]
  #  Averaging images 
   s=np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in
   S01])   
   s_avg=np.array(np.mean(s,axis=(0)),dtype=np.uint16)   
   s_out=Image.fromarray(s_avg)
   #plot histogram
   plt.hist(s_out,bins=auto)
   plt.show()
```

Comment: Nooooo - don't load 100+ images into memory and concatenate copies of them!!!! You will create an enormous demand on your RAM and slow your computer down - especially if they are large satellite images. In order to calculate an average you only need the sum of the items and the number of items. So, read one image and add it to a summation image of a larger type, say int32. Then read the next image and add that to the summation image, and continue till the last. Then divide by how many images you read. This only holds the summation image plus one other in memory at a time.

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert s_avg to an Image, you can compute the histogram of the array using `.ravel()`

```
fnames = [i for i in glob.glob("C:/Users/experiment 1/S01/*.tif")]
s=np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in fnames])

s_avg=np.mean(s,axis=(0)) 

#plot histogram
plt.hist(s_avg.ravel(),bins=100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If i use s_avg.ravel (), I get the following error: in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: ravel

Comment: Can you check the type of s_avg ? it should be a numpy array since it's the output of np.mean(s,axis=(0))

Comment: I have used print(type(s_avg)) and it returns as <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>

Comment: Then you should apply np.array to that object so it becomes an array and has attribute shape !